# Number of transactions and transaction history don't match in XenCoinQt

Tags: bitcoin-core, altcoin, mining-reward, solo-mining

I am solo mining XenCoin using XenCoin QT v0.6.3.3-g069d718-beta.

The number of transactions shown on the overview tab is 9, yet there are 7 transactions listed in the transaction history.

Also, recently I my cgminer 3.7.2 reported that it had found a block. The number of transactions increased on the XenCoinQT overview tab, but the mining reward didn't get credited to my account.

Can anyone explain what's happening? Is someone stealing my coins?

Additionally, is it possible to track all the blocks that are mined by me (solo mining)?

[image: Overview Tab:]

[image: Transactions Tab:]

Comment: You say it doesn't match some 'overview page', could you explain to us what website/service/program this is?

Comment: I have added images of the respective tabs from Xencoin wallet

Comment: You should probably rather direct this question at the developers of the XenCoin wallet or make them aware that you have posted here, if you haven't resolved this question by now. If you have resolved the question, please feel free to post a self-answer.